# Change Google logo attribution position for the static API

Tags: google-maps-api-2

Is there a way to change the position of the Google logo that is displayed at the bottom left of the image received when using the **static maps** API?

Comment: There is no option in the Static Map to change the location of the logo ([docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide)).  In general modification of that logo is against the terms of use.

Comment: @geocodezip That was my understanding from the docs but Monzo are doing it (a very popular British bank) so I thought maybe I missed something

Comment: Maybe they are paying for the privilege.  I haven't seen that (and you didn't provide an example), are you sure they are using Google Static Maps?

Comment: @geocodezip Yeah I am using the image that is coming back from a GET call to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=54.5453995,-2.189167&zoom=15&markers=51.5453995,-3.189167&size=300x150&key=[mykey]

I can't find an exact screenshot of how it shows on my app but it's something similar to https://dribbble.com/shots/3822141-Transactions-on-Monzo only the Google logo is at the bottom left but with padding so that it's not hidden by the square image